# Is there a way to respond_to json and turbo_stream when submitting form through ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails

When submitting a form through Ajax and StimulusJS, is there a way to `respond_to` two formats `json` and `turbo_stream` at the same time or one after another?

Everything works when submitting, just the first `respond_to` is the one that will be used. I want to be able to return the `json` and the `turbo_stream`.

In the rails controller I have:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if current_model.valid?
    format.json { render json: { data: data, status: 200 }  }
    format.turbo_stream { render :success }
  else
    format.json { render json: { data: data, status: 500 }  }
    format.turbo_stream { render :errors }
  end
end
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
  url: form.action,
  method: 'POST',
  data: data
}).then((request) => {
 console.log(request); // Only outputs the first format in respond_to instead of both
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: No unfortunately you can't. Because your Ajax call is hitting only one route. Either the one ending with `.json`, or the one ending with `.turbo_stream`.

Comment: instead of calling ajax call, you can use requestjs library, I think it would work.

Comment: @RahulGupta thanks for the suggestion. I tried using requestjs library since it makes sense for stimulus + rails but the params were not being formatted properly and it seemed that the issue was coming from the library itself. Which then I ended up checking and found a workaround by using something like `window.Turbo.renderStreamMessage(response);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot respond_to json and turbo_stream at a same time.
But if you want store some data for your html page so you can do this as following:

you can store in 1 instance variable.

```
@details = { data: data, status: 200 }
respond_to do |format|
  if current_model.valid?
    format.turbo_stream { render :success, locals: { details: @details } }
  else
    format.turbo_stream { render :errors, locals: { details: @details } }
  end
end
```